# Check if column NULL or empty in Room DB

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I want to get a list of **`MyModel`** whose **`deletedAt`** value is `NULL`.
Here is my table:

```
@Entity(tableName = "my_table")
data class MyModel(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    var id: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "deletedAt")
    var deletedAt: Date? = null
)
```

Dao:

```
@Dao
abstract class MyDao : BaseDao<MyModel> {

@Query("SELECT * from my_table WHERE deletedAt IS NULL")
abstract fun getList(): LiveData<List<MyModel>>
}
```

My TypeConverter:

```
object DateTypeConverter {
@TypeConverter
@JvmStatic// It need to added else gives unwanted data binding error :D
fun fromTimestamp(value: Long?): Date? {
    return if (value == null) null else Date(value)
}

@TypeConverter
@JvmStatic
fun dateToTimestamp(date: Date?): Long? {
    return date?.time
}
```

But it returns all of MyModel data even if deletedAt values are null for some entries.

Comment: your query seems to be wrong, are you checking for createdAt null or deletedAt?
I think it should be `@Query("SELECT * from my_table WHERE deletedAt IS NULL").`

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try to use `NULLIF` to check `null` or `empty` like below

```
NULLIF(deletedAt, '') IS NULL
```

Complete `Query` is

```
@Query("SELECT * from my_table WHERE NULLIF(deletedAt, '') IS NULL")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use in model class

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "user_name")
@NonNull private String strname;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write

```
@Query("SELECT * from my_table WHERE deletedAt IS NULL")
```

a common mistake is writing `like null`

make sure that your data class is

```
data class(
    val id : Long,
    val deletedAt : Long? 
    /....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the String or value in row with a Unique Id

[Check the Room DB Structure and Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yuJ8.png)

> @Query("select *from surveys where attendance_reg_id !=0 and aw_reg_id !=0 and b_form_reg_id !=0 and evs_reg_id !=0 and stu_status_reg_id !=0 and student_pic !="" and b_form_pic !="" and ar_pic !=""")

> suspend fun getCompleteSurveys(): List**